# How to dynamically identify Odd and Evens in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to change the Row Color of a List based if the number is Odd or Even.

This is my code:

```
List {
    ForEach(0..<10) {
        Text("Row \($0)")
    }
    .listRowBackground(Color.red)
}
```

Can someone help me with this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to move the `listRowBackground` modifier inside `ForEach`. This his will give you information whether the row is odd or even and you can set the colour accordingly:

```
List {
        ForEach(0..<10) { number in
            Text("Row \($0)")
            .listRowBackground($0 % 2 == 0 ?  Color.red : Color.blue)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, thats is grate. Thank you very much for your answer.
How would be if I need to write another Text informing if the number is Odd?
Like: 

Row 1 - Odd
Row 2 - Even
...

Comment: Text($0 % 2 == 0 ?  "Even Row \($0)" :  "Odd Row \($0")

Comment: Except in a real app, you usually use the `ForEach` variant that takes an array of model data. Then how do you know if it's even or odd? It's more of a pain.

Answer (score 0):

Here is example:

```
List {
    ForEach(0..<10) { i in
        Text("Row \(i)")
            .listRowBackground(i % 2 == 0 ? Color.red : Color.white)
    }
}
```